# Nested UITableView With Automatic Dimension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a screen that contains 2 levels of nested `UITableViews`.
Each cell of the outer (top level) `TableView` is a `UITableViewCell` That contains a `UITableView`.
[image]

The `TableView` inside each `cell` is drawn correctly, all constraints implemented properly `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is performing correctly.
The problem is with the top level `TableView` cells height, Im trying to set their height with:

```
table.estimatedRowHeight = 400
table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and also return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `heightForRow`.
Cells get height of 45 when their height is 400 or so (dynamic height for each cell).
What am I missing here?
Could it be that the top level `TableView` just cant estimate the inner cell height?

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: have you implement `heightForRow` or `estimatedRowHeight` delegate method ?

Comment: Yes, heightForRow in both TableViews + estimated row height in view did load

Comment: then comment `heightForRow` and implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from it! once try it if it can help! I am not sure but you should once try!

Comment: And second thing you should not use UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects, I mean you should not use nested tableview. Can't you handle with sections ?

Comment: I can design it to be with one tableView only but it make managing complicated

Comment: then also you should prefer that approach !

Comment: estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath didnt helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Tableview Inside Cell](https://github.com/jfrsheriff/Table-View-inside-Cell) . It contains table view inside cell that is completely constructed using auto layout. Hope this may help.